# How to get and post blob from file object

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, image-processing, blob

I get a file object through an html input on-change event in my component.html:

```
input class="hidden" type="file" id="upload-file" name="upload-file" accept=".jpg" ngf-max-size="2MB" (change)="onFileSelected($event)"
```

In my component.ts I set the selectedFile variable equal to the event.target.files[0].

```
onFileSelected(event) {
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  }
```

Now I want to make a POST request to upload the image in the database. The database only excepts something like (blob):

"picture": "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"

I have no idea how to convert it from the file object to this string. Can someone help?
Would be very greatful!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this to get that `base64` string

On your ts file

```
imageDisplay: ArrayBuffer;

onFileSelect(event) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    reader.onload = () =>
      this.imageDisplay = reader.result;
  }
```

`this.imageDisplay` will give you that string.

Comment: thank you for your quick response! But the imageDisplay will be "undefined" because I get the warning "Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'."

Comment: Okay then make it to `ArrayBuffer` instead of `string` and check

Comment: You can read more about it on [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly append `this.selectedFile` data into Form object like `this.formdata.append('profilePic', this.selectedFile);`  and pass formdata to HTTP request.